# How do I know which atoms react during hydrolysis?

Tags: organic-chemistry, water, carbonyl-compounds, hydrolysis

In the hydrolysis of propanamide ($\ce{CH3CH2CONH2}$) how do I know which molecules react with the water?

$$
\ce{CH3CH2CONH2 + H2O -> ?}
$$

I don't know how to split the molecule. In the videos I've watched ([example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MN6edmwMExw#t=612)) it seems as they just assume you know this.

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean which *atoms* react with the water, as clearly the molecule that reacts is propanamide (it's the only non-water molecule in your question).

The product of the reaction is propanoic acid and ammonia.

$$\ce{CH3CH2CONH2 + H2O -> CH3CH2COOH + NH3}$$

The carbonyl carbon in amides (and esters and acyl halides) has a partial positive charge because of the electron withdrawing effect of the carbonyl oxygen.  (Oxygen is very electronegative.)  This makes the carbon atom is activated toward nucleophilic attack.

[This Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nucleophilic_acyl_substitution) has a good explanation and different mechanisms for acid vs. base conditions.